# Angular+Sprint Boot - The service returns a 200 but does not download the zip file

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have to download a zip file built in the back-end part.

When I call the REST EndPoint from Postman it works perfectly and downloads the file, the problem is when I try to download it from my web page made in Angular.

When I call the service from the web it returns a 200 but it does nothing, it does not download anything or not it gives me an error in the browser, however if I get an error in the Kibana logs (The exception is thrown in the "try catch" of the Java controller.):

```
Error to call BS: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: "--MIMEBoundary_6e02a7c1ca86dbb2d10fd6fb6e308ab192e930ffc4a4439f<EOL><EOL>Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"<EOL><EOL>Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary<EOL><EOL>Content-ID: <0.7e02a7c1ca86dbb2d10fd6fb6e308ab192e930ffc4a4439f@apache.org><EOL><EOL><EOL><EOL><jsonObject><errorMessages><Message>Empty List - No data for downloading</Message><correlation-id>10aed9ca-1123-4dbb-a4df-10416e8678c0</correlation-id><Error>Bad request exception</Error><Uri>/file/download</Uri></errorMessages><output/></jsonObject><EOL><EOL>--MIMEBoundary_6e02a7c1ca86dbb2d10fd6fb6e308ab192e930ffc4a4439f--<EOL><EOL>
```

Update of "logger.info":

```
Error to call BS: 400 Bad Request: \"--MIMEBoundary_d08a1c9c5ad2e7d7eec6dc0a4a5c3d3e465e2379d671956a<EOL><EOL>Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=\"text/xml\"<EOL><EOL>Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary<EOL><EOL>Content-ID: <0.c08a1c9c5ad2e7d7eec6dc0a4a5c3d3e465e2379d671956a@apache.org><EOL><EOL><EOL><EOL><jsonObject><errorMessages><Message>Empty List - No data for downloading</Message><correlation-id>22ce3c3e-6bfc-4900-aee2-f56f5984cf05</correlation-id><Error>Bad request exception</Error><Uri>/file/download</Uri></errorMessages><output/></jsonObject><EOL><EOL>--MIMEBoundary_d08a1c9c5ad2e7d7eec6dc0a4a5c3d3e465e2379d671956a--<EOL><EOL>\"\norg.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: \"--MIMEBoundary_d08a1c9c5ad2e7d7eec6dc0a4a5c3d3e465e2379d671956a<EOL><EOL>Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=\"text/xml\"<EOL><EOL>Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary<EOL><EOL>Content-ID: <0.c08a1c9c5ad2e7d7eec6dc0a4a5c3d3e465e2379d671956a@apache.org><EOL><EOL><EOL><EOL><jsonObject><errorMessages><Message>Empty List - No data for downloading</Message><correlation-id>22ce3c3e-6bfc-4900-aee2-f56f5984cf05</correlation-id><Error>Bad request exception</Error><Uri>/file/download</Uri></errorMessages><output/></jsonObject><EOL><EOL>--MIMEBoundary_d08a1c9c5ad2e7d7eec6dc0a4a5c3d3e465e2379d671956a--<EOL><EOL>\"\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:101)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:168)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:751)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//com.enel.platform.solution.secureplat.sam.service.BusinessProxyService.lambda$invoke$7(BusinessProxyService.java:300)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:209)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//com.enel.platform.solution.secureplat.sam.service.BusinessProxyService.invoke(BusinessProxyService.java:271)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//com.enel.platform.solution.web.DownloadFilesController.downloadFiles(DownloadFilesController.java:46)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//com.enel.platform.sdk.solution.webfilter.PlatformRequestFilter.doFilter(PlatformRequestFilter.java:65)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:204)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:168)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:110)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:209)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:107)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter.doFilter(MetadataDisplayFilter.java:84)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.doFilter(SAMLEntryPoint.java:102)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:204)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:204)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:142)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat deployment.solution.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)\n\tat org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.9.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)\n\tat org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)\n\tat org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)\n\tat org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)\n\tat org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.9.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)\n\tat io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\n\tat io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)\n\tat io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)\n\tat org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.9.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)\n\tat io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\n\tat org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\n\tat org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)\n\tat io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:280)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)\n\tat org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)\n\tat org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)\n\tat org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)\n\tat org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)\n\tat org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:260)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)\n\tat io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)\n\tat io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)\n\tat io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)\n\tat org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)\n\tat org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)\n\tat org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)\n\tat org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)\n\tat org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\n
```

I think it's because I'm not sending the body of the POST method right or because I'm not processing it right in the Java part.

This is the component of the Angular part:

```js
this.downloadService.downloadFile(fileName, body).subscribe(response => {
  console.log("response:", response); // here response value is null
  }, error  => {
  console.log("error:", error);
  });
```

This is the service of the Angular part:

```
downloadFile(fileName: string, body?: FilesS3): Observable<any> {
  let headerAccept = [{ "Accept": "application/octet-stream" }];
  return this.service.post<any>("/download", body, headerAccept).pipe();   
}
```

NOTE: variable body in Angular is of type "any".

Controller for the Spring Boot part:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/download")
@Tag(name = "download-files", description = "Download file zip")
public class DownloadFilesController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadFilesController.class);
    @Value("${business.service.resource.download}")
    String businessResourceRegulatorUnit;
    @Autowired
    BusinessProxyService<BusinessSolutionRequest<Void>, Void> businessProxyServiceFile;

    @Operation(summary = "Download files connection to BS")
    @PostMapping(produces = { "application/octet-stream" })
    @SecurePublic()
    public ResponseEntity<Void> downloadFiles(@RequestBody FilesS3 body, HttpServletResponse downloadResponse) {
        BusinessSolutionRequest<FilesS3> businessSolutionRequest = new BusinessSolutionRequest<>();
        logger.info("Body1: " + body);
        if (body != null) {
            businessSolutionRequest.setBody(body);
        }
        logger.info("Invoke download files business service.");
        ConnectionDetails connectionDetails = BusinessSolutionRequest.
                withUri(businessResourceRegulatorUnit).
                httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).
                build();
        logger.info("Body2: " + businessSolutionRequest.getBody());
        logger.info("Uri: " + connectionDetails.getUri().toString());
        try {
            businessProxyServiceFile.invoke(businessSolutionRequest,connectionDetails,response -> {
                logger.info("Body3: " + response.getBody());
                FileCopyUtils.copy(response.getBody(), downloadResponse.getOutputStream());
                return null;
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Error to call BS: " + e);
        }
        logger.info("Prepare for tu return file zip");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
    }
}
```

These are the models of the Sprint Boot part to generate the body:

-FilesS3.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class FilesS3 implements Serializable {
    private ArrayList<S3Link> files = new ArrayList();
}
```

-S3Link.java

```
public class S3Link implements Serializable {
    private String s3Link;
}
```

What could be the problem?

NOTE: In principle I only need the URL to the service and the body, I don't have to send any headers, since the content of the zip is all generated in the back-end.

Comment: uncomment and add headers, as by default it is `"Accept: application/json"`

Comment: I have added the "Accept" header in the Angular part, its value is the content type that the response should return

Answer (score 1):

You have and exception due tu some custom validation resulting in `<Message>Empty List - No data for downloading</Message>` so either it does not work, or you are not sending proper post body.

Also change

```
logger.info("Error to call BS: " + e);
```

to

```
logger.info("Error to call BS: ",e);
```

so you will get actuall stacktrace

Comment: I have updated the "logger.info" to try to see more information, but I just don't see the problem, any ideas @Antoniossss?